# Why is GAE datastore so slow?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Imagine I add a new user in the datastore. I have to add **200 rows** for him (they just contain zeros). But it might take **40 seconds**. The real user that has registered for my website has to wait this time before he proceeds. In MySQL it takes fractions of a second. What do you suggest?

Consider this code. It takes 10 seconds on the Google servers, which is still too slow.

```
def get(self):

    class Movie(ndb.Model):
        title =  ndb.StringProperty (required=True)
        rating = ndb.IntegerProperty (required=True)

        @classmethod
        def populate(cls, n):
            for i in range(n):
                o = cls(title='foo', rating=5)
                o.put()

    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

    Movie.populate(200)

    t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.response.write(t2 - t1) # ~10 seconds
```

Comment: Are you adding users one by one? This is bound to be slow because every API operation makes a roundtrip to the DB servers. You should use multi-put, e.g. put all 200 entities with one put operation.

Comment: You should also consider why you need to create 200 empty entities all at once.  You choice of terminology is also confusing, you refer to users, when creating Movie entities, you use rows when there are now rows just entities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comment - instead of saving entities one-by-one, create a list of entities and save them with [multi-put](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#multiple).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a more sensible data model, frankly. There's no reason at all to create a model with 200 fields. Not only will the initial setup take ages, but loading each instance will be expensive, and saving will be exceedingly expensive.

In any case, you almost certainly don't need to instantiate all the fields from the start.

(Also, I must say that even with 200 fields, taking 40 seconds to save seems extremely unlikely. You are probably doing something strange, but without seeing any code it's impossible to tell.)

Comment: By "fields" I meant not "properties" but actualy "rows" (in relative db sense). Adding new rows (records) is very slow in GAE.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Still need to see some code though. And is this in development or production?

Comment: Production. I don't provide code because the idea is so easy. Imagine a model for a user with just two properties for his name and email. Adding 200 new users would take about 40 seconds. And I don't know how to populate the datastore quickly.

Comment: Well, the reason I asked you for code is that that absolutely does not match my experience. You can easily create hundreds of rows in a few seconds.